# Limit Gridview to 50 rows no matter how large myDataSet is

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to limit Gridview to 50 rows? I would eventually like to have a DropDownList choosing 0-50,51-100 and so forth. The dataset,ds, fits nicely into the the datatable,dt, with the Table command.

```
       conn = "connection string works"
       cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM table1;"
       Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
               Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    dt = ds.Tables(0)
                    for k = 1 to 50
                        dt.Rows.Add()'???
                    Next k
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: add `AllowPaging` and `PageSize=50` attirbute to the gridview control

Comment: The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.

Comment: add `OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"`

Answer (score 0):

add `AllowPaging="True"`, `PageSize=50` and `OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"` attirbute to the gridview control and implment the vent handler as shown below

```
   protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {   
        gridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        //rebind data to the gridview
    }
```